# Change column type, Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-7

I have a column   `$table->date('start_date');` , and I want to store data and time so I will need `timestamp`.
I already have some date in my current table, so I am not sure what to do without deleting existing data.

I find some solutions (on changing data type) that involve doctrine, but from what I read, Supported Laravel Versions is 6.x and I am using 7.

Any solutions?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Have you tried/tested the Laravel 6 examples with your local setup?

Comment: I didn't, my case involves some existing data, in that column, not just modifying .

Comment: You can add a new column named `$table->dateTime('new_start_date');` and migrate it (not refresh). Then make a function that will copy the date from `start_date` to `new_start_date` where time will be `00:00:00` or something.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PostgreSQL documentation you can convert a date to timestamp by using `to_timestamp()` function
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-formatting.html

You have two choices :

- Create a new column and create a script which convert all entries in the right format
- Create a script which update all the datas you need to into the already existing table